# Use GRASS-GIS features in a python script

Tags: python, grass-gis

I'm writing a python script in which I want to import some grass functions.
To test the script I used a test command like **r.null**, but the code returns an error before that.
The procedure I'm using is shown in this example:

```
import os

from grass_session import Session
from grass.script import core as gcore

import grass.script as gscript
import grass.script.setup as gsetup

gisdb = 'path/to/Grass_session'
inputFile  = os.path.join(gisdb,'elevation.tif')
outputFile = os.path.join(gisdb,'output_elevation.tif')

location_name = 'Work_dir'
mapset = 'mapset'

PERMANENT = Session()
PERMANENT.open(gisdb=gisdb, location=location_name, mapset=mapset,
               create_opts='EPSG:32632')

west = 1083988.1464839160908014
south = 4535980.4144736304879189
east = 1163008.1464839160908014
north = 4582000.4144736304879189

gscript.run_command('g.region', n=4582000.4144736304879189, s=4535980.4144736304879189, e=1163008.1464839160908014, w=1083988.1464839160908014, ewres=20, nsres=20, verbose=True, flags='p')

gscript.run_command('r.in.gdal', input = inputFile,
                    output= outputFile, overwrite = True)

gscript.run_command("r.null", map = 'elevation.tif', setnull = 0)
```

The error is:

```
GRASSBIN: grass74
GISBASE: /usr/lib/grass74
ERROR: Unable to open element file <> for <DEFAULT_WIND@PERMANENT>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    gscript.run_command('g.region', n=4582000.4144736304879189, s=4535980.4144736304879189, e=1163008.1464839160908014, w=1083988.1464839160908014, ewres=20, nsres=20, verbose=True, flags='p')
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 421, in run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 332, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/etc/python/grass/exceptions/__init__.py", line 68, in __init__
    msg = _("Module run %s %s ended with error") % (module, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 369, in lgettext
    return tmsg.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I was able to use the **r.region** and **r.ingdal** commands without error, but I get an error with the **r.null** command:

```
import os

from grass_session import Session
from grass.script import core as gcore
import grass.script as gscript
import grass.script.setup as gsetup

gisdb = 'path/to/Grass_session'

inputFile  = os.path.join(gisdb,'elevation.tif')
outputFile = os.path.join(gisdb,'output_elevation.tif')

location_name = 'Work_dir'
mapset = 'PERMANENT'

PERMANENT = Session()
PERMANENT.open(gisdb=gisdb, location=location_name, mapset=mapset,
               create_opts='EPSG:32632')

gscript.run_command('g.region', n=4588802.4653103761374950, s=4529242.1501442901790142, e=1167158.4690597453154624, w=1080258.9182251752354205, ewres=20, nsres=20, verbose=True, flags='p')


gscript.run_command('r.in.gdal', overwrite = True, input = inputFile, output= 'output_elevation.tif')           
gscript.run_command("r.null", map = 'elevation.tif', setnull = 0)
```

The error is:

```
GRASSBIN: grass74
GISBASE: /usr/lib/grass74
path/to/Grass_session/elevation.tif
projection: 1 (UTM)
zone:       32
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      4588802.46531
south:      4529242.15014
west:       1080258.91823
east:       1167158.46906
nsres:      20.00010583
ewres:      19.99989662
rows:       2978
cols:       4345
cells:      12939410
WARNING: Raster map <output_elevation.tif> already exists and will be
         overwritten
Importing raster map <output_elevation.tif>...
 100%
ERROR: Raster map <elevation.tif> not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    gscript.run_command("r.null", map = 'elevation.tif', setnull = 0)
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 421, in run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 332, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/etc/python/grass/exceptions/__init__.py", line 68, in __init__
    msg = _("Module run %s %s ended with error") % (module, code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 369, in lgettext
    return tmsg.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: It is looking for something in `PERMANENT`, but you create only `mapset='mapset'`. Following their example, try working in `mapset='PERMANENT'` first. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]
I found a solution. Below is the script I use:

```
from grass_session import Session
from grass.script import core as gcore

import grass.script as gscript
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
import os
import shutil

gisdb = os.getcwd()

inputFile = 'elevation.tif'
inputFile_path  = os.path.join(gisdb, inputFile)

outputFile = '{}.out.tif'.format(inputFile)
print outputFile
outputFile_path = os.path.join(gisdb,outputFile)

location_name = 'Work_dir'
mapset = 'PERMANENT'

# clean location
shutil.rmtree(location_name)

PERMANENT = Session()
PERMANENT.open(gisdb=gisdb, location=location_name, mapset=mapset,
               create_opts='EPSG:32632')

n=4588802.4653103761374950
s=4529242.1501442901790142
e=1167158.4690597453154624
w=1080258.9182251752354205

gscript.run_command('g.region', n=n, s=s, e=e, w=w, ewres=20, nsres=20, verbose=True, flags='p')

gscript.run_command('r.in.gdal', overwrite = True, input = inputFile, output = outputFile)          
gscript.run_command("r.null", map = outputFile, setnull = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this line

```
PERMANENT.open(gisdb=gisdb, location=location_name, mapset=mapset,
```

to this line:

```
PERMANENT.open(gisdb=gisdb, location=location_name,
```

Then it starts (didn't check the rest). It operated in the PERMANENT mapset then (which is the default mapset to have anyway).

A full example is available in the GRASS GIS Wiki [here](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_an_external_library:_grass-session).